# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#882e9 relayoutBoundary=up5

Tags: flutter

I'm developing an app in flutter and this is my code:

**Code 1**:

[image: code 1]

**Code 2**:

[image: code 2]

**Code 3**:

[image: code 3]

The error I'm getting is:

[image: error image]

Comment: Copy-pasted code is preferred to images of code as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ListView inside a Container/SizedBox and provide height to it.